# How to use Extjs delegate pattern to add tooltip on Extjs toolbar

Tags: extjs4

I used Extjs tool bar with many buttons.can i know how to apply tool tip for that buttons with delegate pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here my toolbar button

```
xtype: 'toolbar',
dock: 'top',
id: 'toolbar-id',
items: [
    {
    xtype: 'button1',
    id: 'button-id1',
    cls: 'tb-btn',
    qtipText: 'tool tip description',
    qtipTitle: 'tool tip title'
    },
    {
    xtype: 'button2',
    id: 'button-id2',
    cls: 'tb-btn',
    qtipText: 'tool tip description',
    qtipTitle: 'tool tip title'
    }
    ]
```

apply tooltip with using delegate pattern

```
render: function(Component, eOpts) {

    Component.tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
        target: Component.el,
        delegate: '.tb-btn',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        listeners: {
            beforeshow: function updateTipBody(tip) {
                var btnData = Component.getComponent(tip.triggerElement.id);
                tip.update("<div class='tol-box'><h4 class='tool-tip-title'>" + btnData.qtipTitle + '</h4><p>' + btnData.qtipText + "</p></div>");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code should be like this :

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    fields: ['company', 'price', 'change'],
    data: [
        ['3m Co',                               71.72, 0.02],
        ['Alcoa Inc',                           29.01, 0.42],
        ['Altria Group Inc',                    83.81, 0.28],
        ['American Express Company',            52.55, 0.01],
        ['American International Group, Inc.',  64.13, 0.31],
        ['AT&T Inc.',                           31.61, -0.48]
    ]
});

var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Array Grid',
    store: store,
    columns: [
        {text: 'Company', flex: 1, dataIndex: 'company'},
        {text: 'Price', width: 75, dataIndex: 'price'},
        {text: 'Change', width: 75, dataIndex: 'change'}
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

grid.getView().on('render', function(view) {
    view.tip = Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
        // The overall target element.
        target: view.el,
        // Each grid row causes its own seperate show and hide.
        delegate: view.itemSelector,
        // Moving within the row should not hide the tip.
        trackMouse: true,
        // Render immediately so that tip.body can be referenced prior to the first show.
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        listeners: {
            // Change content dynamically depending on which element triggered the show.
            beforeshow: function updateTipBody(tip) {
                tip.update('Over company "' + view.getRecord(tip.triggerElement).get('company') + '"');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

If you want more examples or details ,you can refer [this Site](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.tip.ToolTip).

Comment: This is for grid panel, but i need to add delegate pattern for Ext toolbar